# Printing columns in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a school assignment that needs to be written in Java, Python, and R. I'm having trouble with the formatting in Python.

Requirements of program: Write a Python program that uses two nested FOR loops. The values used in the outer loop will be a user input value. The inner loop will use the input value divided by 2. Print a simple statement showing the values using the range of 1 to the user input number in the outer loop. The inner loop will print 1 to the divided result.

**Java code (desired output)**

```java
package module1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Numbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter a number: \n");

            int n = input.nextInt();
            input.close();
            
            int val = n/2;
            
            for (int i=1;i<=n; i++) {
                System.out.print(i);
                for (int j=1; j<=val; j++) {
                    System.out.print("\t" +j);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    }
}
```

**Python code (printing rows, not columns)**

```py
import sys


def main():
    print("Please enter a number: ")
    n = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    val = n // 2
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(i, end="")
        for j in range(1, val+1):
            print("\t", j, end="")
            print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[Java output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIXCP.png)

[Python output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpMmx.png)

Comment: This is going to get closed because you've just asked people to do your homework. I would recommend deleting this question and trying again - next time don't mention homework, and you also have to say what you tried and *the way in which it doesn't work*.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the tips. My assignment is already done, I just want to understand it better. I emailed my prof. for guidance and he said what I have is fine and left it at that. I'm just trying to understand how to format it into columns so that I know for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is **very important** in Python. The `print()` on line 12 is a part of the 2nd `for` loop, which is why you are getting an undesirable output. You just need to remove four spaces before `print()` in order to make your code work correctly.

Here is your code with the aforementioned modification:

```py
import sys


def main():
    print("Please enter a number: ")
    n = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    val = n // 2
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(i, end="")
        for j in range(1, val+1):
            print("\t", j, end="")
        print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @user85421 Yes, you are correct. I've modified my answer.

Comment: @AleksaMajkic Thank you for clarifying that. It was right in front of me and I just wasn't seeing it. I appreciate you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you search for?

```
def main():
    n = int(input("Please enter a number: \n"))
    val = int(n/2)
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print('\n', i, end="")
        for j in range(1, val+1):
            print("\t", j, end="")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
Please enter a number: 
6

 1   1   2   3
 2   1   2   3
 3   1   2   3
 4   1   2   3
 5   1   2   3
 6   1   2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to *"un-indent"* the second *print* call of the *inner for-loop*.

```py
for j in range(1, val+1):
    print("\t", j, end="")
print()
```

Additionally, utilize a *[formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings)* to append the *j* value.

```py
print(f"\t{j}", end="")
```

And, you can use the *[input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)* *built-in function*

```py
n = int(input("Please enter a number: ").strip())
```

Here is the re-factor.

```py
import sys


def main():
    print("Please enter a number: ")
    n = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    val = n // 2
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(i, end="")
        for j in range(1, val+1):
            print(f"\t{j}", end="")
        print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
Please enter a number: 
6
1   1   2   3
2   1   2   3
3   1   2   3
4   1   2   3
5   1   2   3
6   1   2   3
```